# How to concatenate several images given a list

Tags: python, opencv, concatenation

I have a certain scrip that spits a procedurally generated list of lists of strings of what would my tiles be in a square grid:

```
grid = [['grass', 'grass', 'trees'], 
['flowers', 'grass', 'grass'], 
['grass', 'flowers', 'grass']]
```

Now I can't seem to find a way to use these names in order to build an image using images of each tile

```
grass = cv2.imread('grass.png')
flowers = cv2.imread('flowers.png')
trees = cv2.imread('trees.png')
```

I am sorry I am quite new here, this is what I tried to implement:

```
image_grid = None
image_row = None

for row in grid:
    for item in row:
        if image_row is None:
            image_row = eval(item)
        else:
            image_row = cv2.hconcat([image_row, eval(item)])

    if image_grid is None:
        image_grid = image_row
    else:
        image_grid = cv2.vconcat([image_grid, image_row])

cv2.imshow('grid', image_grid)
cv2.waitKey()
```

But it returns cv2.error: OpenCV(4.5.5) D:\a\opencv-python\opencv-python\opencv\modules\core\src\matrix_operations.cpp:67: error: (-215:Assertion failed)

Comment: sorry man couldn't understand your question please tell what do you want to do do you want an image with all the things in the list?

Comment: Yes, I want to output an image built by the tiles in the table. Each of the tiles I have is a 64x64 png if it helps. I have been trying for loops and the methods cv2.hconcat() and cv2.vconcat() but to no success.

Comment: **"no success"** means you have to put your attempt in the question. don't wait for people to *ask* before providing information. you want help, be forthcoming. please take the [tour] and review [ask] and [mre].

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow, please post your code so far and explain what are the specific problems with your existing implementation or the documentation that you have used!

Comment: Sorry, I edited the post to include what I tried to implement.